# Override the default slot in VueFormulate's FormulateInput

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-formulate

There is a section in the Vue Formulate documentation that describes how to override the `label` slot of the FormulateInput component. Similarly, I would like to overwrite the `default` slot in order to customize it, but it seems it does not work. Is there a special way to overwrite it? Is it even possible to override the `default` slot?

[image]

[Link to the FormulateVue documentation](https://vueformulate.com/guide/inputs/slots/#available-slots)